# WDIO docker run: [1643987609.767][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)

Tags: docker, jenkins, wdio

There is an error while run wdio test in Docker using Jenkins. I have no idea how to solve this problem :(
The same config run successfully on local env (windows + docker).

This is wdio config. I used default dockerOptions.
wdio.conf

```
import { config as sharedConfig } from './wdio.shared.conf'

export const config: WebdriverIO.Config = {
    ...sharedConfig,
    ...{
        host: 'localhost',
        services: ['docker'],
        dockerLogs: './logs',
        dockerOptions: {
            image:  'selenium/standalone-chrome:4.1.2-20220131',
            healthCheck: {
                url: 'http://localhost:4444',
                maxRetries: 3,
                inspectInterval: 7000,
                startDelay: 15000
            },
            options: {
                p: ['4444:4444'],
                shmSize: '2g'
            }
        },
        capabilities: [{
            acceptInsecureCerts: true,
            browserName: 'chrome',
            browserVersion: 'latest',
            'goog:chromeOptions': {
                args: [ '--verbose', '--headless', '--disable-gpu', 'window-size=1920,1800','--no-sandbox', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--disable-extensions'],
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

After that, I try to run UI test via jenkins:

```
19:37:34  Run `npm audit` for details.
19:37:34  + npm run test:ci -- --spec ./test/specs/claim.BNB.spec.ts
19:37:34  
19:37:34  > jasmine-boilerplate@1.0.0 test:ci
19:37:34  > wdio run wdio.ci.conf.ts
```

And got an error.
Logs attached:

wdio.log

```
2022-02-04T16:59:20.725Z DEBUG @wdio/utils:initialiseServices: initialise service "docker" as NPM package
2022-02-04T16:59:20.758Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2022-02-04T16:59:20.760Z DEBUG wdio-docker-service: Docker command: docker run --cidfile /home/jenkins/workspace/tests_e2e1_configure_CI_CD/e2e/selenium_standalone_chrome_latest.cid --rm -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 --shm-size 2g selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
2022-02-04T16:59:20.769Z WARN wdio-docker-service: Connecting dockerEventsListener: 6283
2022-02-04T16:59:20.772Z INFO wdio-docker-service: Cleaning up CID files
2022-02-04T16:59:20.834Z INFO wdio-docker-service: Launching docker image 'selenium/standalone-chrome:latest'
2022-02-04T16:59:20.841Z INFO wdio-docker-service: Docker container is ready
2022-02-04T16:59:20.841Z DEBUG @wdio/cli:utils: Finished to run "onPrepare" hook in 82ms
2022-02-04T16:59:20.842Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2022-02-04T16:59:20.843Z DEBUG @wdio/cli:utils: Finished to run "onWorkerStart" hook in 0ms
2022-02-04T16:59:20.843Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: run,wdio.ci.conf.ts,--spec,./test/specs/claim.BNB.spec.ts
2022-02-04T16:59:22.034Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner: Runner 0-0 finished with exit code 1
2022-02-04T16:59:22.035Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook
2022-02-04T16:59:22.036Z INFO wdio-docker-service: Shutting down running container
2022-02-04T16:59:32.372Z INFO wdio-docker-service: Cleaning up CID files
2022-02-04T16:59:32.373Z INFO wdio-docker-service: Docker container has stopped
2022-02-04T16:59:32.374Z WARN wdio-docker-service: Disconnecting dockerEventsListener: 6283
2022-02-04T16:59:32.374Z DEBUG @wdio/cli:utils: Finished to run "onComplete" hook in 10339ms
2022-02-04T16:59:32.430Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2022-02-04T16:59:32.681Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
```

wdio-0-0.log

```
2022-02-04T16:59:21.223Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
2022-02-04T16:59:21.513Z DEBUG @wdio/config:utils: Found 'ts-node' package, auto-compiling TypeScript files
2022-02-04T16:59:21.714Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner:utils: init remote session
2022-02-04T16:59:21.717Z DEBUG @wdio/utils:initialiseServices: initialise service "docker" as NPM package
2022-02-04T16:59:21.828Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner:utils: init remote session
2022-02-04T16:59:21.840Z INFO devtools:puppeteer: Initiate new session using the DevTools protocol
2022-02-04T16:59:21.841Z INFO devtools: Launch Google Chrome with flags: --enable-automation --disable-popup-blocking --disable-extensions --disable-background-networking --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-sync --metrics-recording-only --disable-default-apps --mute-audio --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-breakpad --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-renderer-backgrounding --force-fieldtrials=*BackgroundTracing/default/ --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-features=site-per-process,TranslateUI,BlinkGenPropertyTrees --window-position=0,0 --window-size=1200,900 --headless --disable-gpu --window-size=1920,1800 --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions
2022-02-04T16:59:21.911Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: 
    at new LauncherError (/home/jenkins/workspace/tests_e2e1_configure_CI_CD/e2e/node_modules/chrome-launcher/src/utils.ts:31:18)
    at new ChromePathNotSetError (/home/jenkins/workspace/tests_e2e1_configure_CI_CD/e2e/node_modules/chrome-launcher/dist/utils.js:33:9)
    at Object.linux (/home/jenkins/workspace/tests_e2e1_configure_CI_CD/e2e/node_modules/chrome-launcher/src/chrome-finder.ts:153:11)
    at Function.getFirstInstallation (/home/jenkins/workspace/tests_e2e1_configure_CI_CD/e2e/node_modules/chrome-launcher/src/chrome-launcher.ts:182:61)
    at Launcher.launch (/home/jenkins/workspace/tests_e2e1_configure_CI_CD/e2e/node_modules/chrome-launcher/src/chrome-launcher.ts:252:37)
    at launch (/home/jenkins/workspace/tests_e2e1_configure_CI_CD/e2e/node_modules/chrome-launcher/src/chrome-launcher.ts:74:18)
    at launchChrome (/home/jenkins/workspace/tests_e2e1_configure_CI_CD/e2e/node_modules/devtools/build/launcher.js:80:55)
    at launch (/home/jenkins/workspace/tests_e2e1_configure_CI_CD/e2e/node_modules/devtools/build/launcher.js:179:16)
    at Function.newSession (/home/jenkins/workspace/tests_e2e1_configure_CI_CD/e2e/node_modules/devtools/build/index.js:50:54)
    at remote (/home/jenkins/workspace/tests_e2e1_configure_CI_CD/e2e/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:67:43)
```

wdio-chromedriver.log

```
Starting ChromeDriver 97.0.4692.71 (adefa7837d02a07a604c1e6eff0b3a09422ab88d-refs/branch-heads/4692@{#1247}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1643987609.767][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
```

docker-log.txt

```
2022-02-04 16:59:21,482 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/selenium.conf" during parsing
2022-02-04 16:59:21,484 INFO supervisord started with pid 7
Trapped SIGTERM/SIGINT/x so shutting down supervisord...
2022-02-04 16:59:22,487 INFO spawned: 'xvfb' with pid 9
2022-02-04 16:59:22,489 INFO spawned: 'vnc' with pid 10
2022-02-04 16:59:22,491 INFO spawned: 'novnc' with pid 11
2022-02-04 16:59:22,492 INFO spawned: 'selenium-standalone' with pid 12
2022-02-04 16:59:22,493 WARN received SIGTERM indicating exit request
2022-02-04 16:59:22,493 INFO waiting for xvfb, vnc, novnc, selenium-standalone to die
Setting up SE_NODE_GRID_URL...
2022-02-04 16:59:22,501 INFO success: xvfb entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2022-02-04 16:59:22,501 INFO success: vnc entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2022-02-04 16:59:22,501 INFO success: novnc entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
Selenium Grid Standalone configuration: 
[network]
relax-checks = true

[node]
session-timeout = "300"
override-max-sessions = false
detect-drivers = false
max-sessions = 1

[[node.driver-configuration]]
display-name = "chrome"
stereotype = '{"browserName": "chrome", "browserVersion": "97.0", "platformName": "Linux"}'
max-sessions = 1

Starting Selenium Grid Standalone...
16:59:22.930 INFO [LoggingOptions.configureLogEncoding] - Using the system default encoding
16:59:22.939 INFO [OpenTelemetryTracer.createTracer] - Using OpenTelemetry for tracing
16:59:23.452 INFO [NodeOptions.getSessionFactories] - Detected 4 available processors
16:59:23.493 INFO [NodeOptions.report] - Adding chrome for {"browserVersion": "97.0","browserName": "chrome","platformName": "Linux","se:vncEnabled": true} 1 times
16:59:23.505 INFO [Node.<init>] - Binding additional locator mechanisms: name, id, relative
16:59:23.526 INFO [LocalDistributor.add] - Added node 150c2c05-2b08-4ba9-929a-45fef66bb193 at http://172.17.0.2:4444. Health check every 120s
16:59:23.540 INFO [GridModel.setAvailability] - Switching node 150c2c05-2b08-4ba9-929a-45fef66bb193 (uri: http://172.17.0.2:4444) from DOWN to UP
16:59:23.645 INFO [Standalone.execute] - Started Selenium Standalone 4.1.2 (revision 9a5a329c5a): http://172.17.0.2:4444
2022-02-04 16:59:26,091 INFO waiting for xvfb, vnc, novnc, selenium-standalone to die
2022-02-04 16:59:29,095 INFO waiting for xvfb, vnc, novnc, selenium-standalone to die
2022-02-04 16:59:32,097 INFO waiting for xvfb, vnc, novnc, selenium-standalone to die
```